# Makefile Include directive while migrating from Unix to Linux

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I am tasked with migrating an ancient C++ based code, from Unix environment to Linux.
The project is made up of multiple Makefiles, for different "modules" of the library.
I have resolved some problems, however now having trouble with the include directive.

Apparently, the way the Makefiles are constructed, is to have a **separate** include directives, for different files, and it worked for years in the Unix server.

For example:

```
include ../../../../util/genmake.def

processControl.slOBJS = processControl.o
outputControlOBJS = outputControl.o
inputControlOBJS = inputControl.o
cleanList  = *.o *.C *.out processControl.sl outputControl inputControl

all: processControl.sl  outputControl inputControl

processControl.sl: $(processControl.slOBJS)
        include ../../../../util/genmake.slinc

outputControl: $(outputControlOBJS)
        include ../../../../util/genmake.exeinc

inputControl: $(inputControlOBJS)
        include ../../../../util/genmake.exeinc

include ../../../../util/genmake.inc
```

You can see here that, tabbed includes, only refer to the specified targets! They are part of the recipe for that target.

However, this construct is NOT working in Linux, I get this error:

```
include ../../../../util/genmake.slinc
make: include: Command not found
make: *** [processControl.sl] Error 127
```

Obviously I can't just remove the tab, because the include should be only for that target...

So, I have tried to replace it with a shell 'source' command to source the included file like:

```
        source ../../../../util/genmake.slinc
```

This doesnt work apparently, and I also tried to bring in the included code directly into the include file (commenting out the include command) - this handles the errors related to Makefile, but this is not a good solution, as it would be really hard to migrate and maintain it, having to replicate the same code all over the project into all modules, and then of course every tiny change I would have to reflect on all files.

Can any Make expert please advice on this issue?
Also, generally any advice on how best to approach this migration task, would be welcome :)

Thanks!

EDIT- Extra information:
Content of genmake.slinc:

---

```
#######################################################################
## This include will inherit the target and dependent files in
## a make file that inlcudes it.
## The inclusion of this file should look like:
##
## {target}: {dependent file list}
## include genmake.slinc
##
#######################################################################
        @echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
        @echo " (G) Creating shared library $@ from $($(MaKeObJs:x=$(@)OBJS))";
        @echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
        @echo "$(CPP) -b -o $@ $($(MaKeObJs:x=$(@)OBJS))"
        @$(CPP) -b -o $@ $($(MaKeObJs:x=$(@)OBJS))
        @echo " Moving shared library to $(SHLIBINSTALL) as lib$(@)"
        @$(MV) $@ $(SHLIBINSTALL)/lib$(@)
        @echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
```

---

Those are tabs before @.

Now content of genmake.exeinc:

---

```
#######################################################################
## This include will inherit the target and dependent files in
## a make file that inlcudes it.
## The inclusion of this file should look like:
##
## {target}: {dependent file list}
## include /opt/app/fba/util/genmake.exeinc
##
#######################################################################
        @cp $(SHLIBINSTALL)/* $(TEMP_SHLIB_DIR)/.
        @echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
        @echo " (G) Linking $($(MaKeObJs:x=$(@)OBJS)) to make $@ "
        @echo "     LDOPTS set to: $(LDOPTS)"
#       @echo "  $(PURIFY) $(LD) "
        @echo "  SHLIB Temp Path: $(TEMP_SHLIB_DIR)
        @echo "     FBA libraries: $(FBALIB)"
        @echo "     Application libraries: $(APPLIBS)"
        $(PURIFY) $(LD) -o $@ $($(MaKeObJs:x=$(@)OBJS)) \
                $(CXXOPTS) \
                $(LDFLAGS) \
                $(FBALIB) \
                $(PROLDLIBS) \
                `cat /usr/local/opt/oracle/product/t1c3d771/lib/ldflags`  \
                `cat /usr/local/opt/oracle/product/t1c3d771/lib/sysliblist` \
                $(APPLIBS)
        @echo " Moving executable to $(EXEINSTALL) "
        @$(MV) $@ $(EXEINSTALL)
        @echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
```

---

If I go to the Makefile, and remove leading tabs on the includes, I get this error:
    ../../../../util/genmake.slinc:10: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.

Comment: @DOUG If the tab is removed, the include is no longer part of the recipe.

Comment: From GNU Make:  "Extra spaces are allowed and ignored at the beginning of the line, but the first character must not be a tab (or the value of .RECIPEPREFIX)—if the line begins with a tab, it will be considered a recipe line. Whitespace is required between include and the file names, and between file names; extra whitespace is ignored there and at the end of the directive. A comment starting with ‘#’ is allowed at the end of the line. If the file names contain any variable or function references, they are expanded. See How to Use Variables. "   Perhaps Make has changed?

Comment: If make indeed changed from UNIX to Linux, the how do you suggest that I resolve this issues of multiple different includes for every target in a make file?  Also would be nice to know exactly in what make version this behavior was changed, as it sounds like a step back from a more advanced feature.

Comment: Interesting.  I am (currently) of the opinion that Make reads all the makefile, and all the include makefiles, before it starts processing any rules.  Therefore the order-of-include (w.r.t. recipe line) should not make a difference.  IMHO, your example seems to contradict that.  Have you tried removing the tab to see if the build works anyway?  If they contradict each other, not sure what to do.

Comment: @Doug: I am out of office, will check tomorrow although I think that I did try.. Don't remember what was the outcome or exactly why its not acceptable. Will update tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Carmageddon I do not know what `genmake.slinc` and `genmake.exelinc` look like but as they are included in the recipe, I believe that they look very much like shell scripts. If that's the case you could modify them to actually be shell scripts and just execute them. the caveat is that variable expansion won't be done by make, therefore you'd need to use `export` for the relevant variable assignments

Comment: It looks to me that `include` may be an executable on the Unix server and not a directive. Have you made sure that isn't the case?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I checked and updated the question, when I remove leading tabs in Makefile, I get this error:  ../../../../util/genmake.slinc:10: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop. I also posted the slinc file contents in the question for your reference.

Comment: @Alden - I checked, include is not a command recognized on the old Unix server.

Comment: In "genmake.exeinc" I see $(PURIFY) used as a command.  This might the Rational tool "purify".  From manual: "Purify uses Object Code Insertion (OCI) technology to instrument a copy of your object code, inserting checking instructions before every memory operation.
When you run the instrumented program, Purify reports run-time
errors and memory leaks in the Purify Viewer."   It appears Linux is a supported platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the target into the include as a variable:
For instance, `genmake.exeinc` would become:

```
$(targetControl): $(depControlOBJS)
    @cp $(SHLIBINSTALL)/* $(TEMP_SHLIB_DIR)/.
    @echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
    @echo " (G) Linking $($(MaKeObJs:x=$(@)OBJS)) to make $@ "
    @echo "     LDOPTS set to: $(LDOPTS)"
#   @echo "  $(PURIFY) $(LD) "
    @echo "  SHLIB Temp Path: $(TEMP_SHLIB_DIR)
    @echo "     FBA libraries: $(FBALIB)"
    @echo "     Application libraries: $(APPLIBS)"
    $(PURIFY) $(LD) -o $@ $($(MaKeObJs:x=$(@)OBJS)) \
            $(CXXOPTS) \
            $(LDFLAGS) \
            $(FBALIB) \
            $(PROLDLIBS) \
            `cat /usr/local/opt/oracle/product/t1c3d771/lib/ldflags`  \
            `cat /usr/local/opt/oracle/product/t1c3d771/lib/sysliblist` \
            $(APPLIBS)
    @echo " Moving executable to $(EXEINSTALL) "
    @$(MV) $@ $(EXEINSTALL)
    @echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
```

And then modify the relevant parts of your makefile as follows:

```
#outputControl: $(outputControlOBJS)
targetControl=outputControl
depControlOBJS=$(outputControlOBJS)
include ../../../../util/genmake.exeinc

#inputControl: $(inputControlOBJS)
targetControl=inputControl
depControlOBJS=$(inputControlOBJS)
include ../../../../util/genmake.exeinc
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! thank you! Although the other awk solution is smart, its not elegant, after all...

Answer (score 1):

My idea of letting **gnumake** do all processing proved to be wrong. The relevant differences between *HP-UX 11i Version 1* and the latest Linux build are as follows:

- <kbd>TAB</kbd> before `include` was silently ignored; now it is interpreted as recipe prefix, and **gnu make** tries to find **include** executable on your machine.
- `include` in **gnu make** <s>silently adds an empty line to the merged output</s> resets the recipe on the boundary of each *included* file (as [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) correctly pointed out), thus included file cannot consist of recipe statements only.

If the included files don't use the same trick recursively (and in your example they seem to be plain actions, with no additional **include** statements), you can use **awk** to prepare the merged Makefile on the fly like this:

```
awk '{ if (NF == 2 && $1 == "include") { while ((getline line < $2) > 0) print line ; close($2) } else print }' Makefile | make -f -
```

The script above will handle files as they are on your system, no editing is necessary.

Comment: I think I understand now, its run at command line. It gives the following error: make: /dev/stdin: No such device or address
make: *** No targets.  Stop.

Comment: I tested by manually directing into temp make file output and then using make -f to test - it works! (falls on other errors, but that is beside the point) - thanks! Just Need to resolve the stdin error...

Comment: Also, I'd like to learn how did you debug to reach this conclusion: "include in gnu make silently adds an empty line to the merged output"

Comment: The statement about "silently adding an empty line" is not true.  It's possible the author believes that if there's a blank line between the rule introduction and the recipe, then the recipe is not part of the rule but that's not correct: you can intersperse blank lines, comments, ifdefs, etc. inside a recipe.  It's simpler than that: in GNU make when an `include` statement is parsed, before the file is included any in-progress rule definition is completed.  A rule definition cannot span an included file in GNU make.

Comment: @MadScientist you are right! It's really more tricky logic than I expected. Thanks for correction!

Comment: Sorry for delay, the official way to use _pipe_ as input file for **make** is like this: `make -f -`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thank you! I keep this is reserved and voted up the solution, unfortunately the other solution is much more elegant and easier to scale up as a solution for the entire project, so I had to accept it, despite the time and energy you invested into doing this smart solution which I liked :)

Comment: It's OK, I learned a lot looking for the best answer. My goal was to make minimum editing, and the result was it: 0 changes. But I understand that anyway you need to edit the make files because the toolchain also changed when you moved from HP UX to Linux.